# How to tag links that they show up as social network referrals in google analytics

Tags: email, google-analytics, whatsapp, universal-analytics

Besides facebook and twitter I'm using email and whatsapp sharing button on my website, which are quite used a lot.

Unter social network referrals I can see Facebook and Google+ (I'm surprised that twitter doesn't show up? since it has a referrer to!) so I was wondering how to get the email and whatsapp stats there?

[image: Facebook and Google+ as social network referrals]

I'm curious how much direct traffic is coming from email and whatsapp. Gonna add whatsapp button too tonight. Since it is simple I'm thinking of tagging all the urls e.g. with a #ref=abc. I was wondering whats the best way to tag these links shared by email and whatsapp to get good readable stats? Thus I was wondering how I have to tag urls that they show up as social network referrals?

To delimit I do know how to tag links with utm terms to show up as campaigns, however I'd rather prefer to show them in social network referrals section there they belong in my opinion.

I really appreciate your thoughts and expertise!

Comment: The default channel definitions use one of social|social-network|social-media|sm|social network|social media in the "medium" campaign parameter to group a link into social media, so it might be worth testing if one of these works to get the links into the social referrals report.

Comment: Had the same thought yesterday. Implemented it this way. Waiting for some data to aggregate to see in the stats.

Comment: @EikePierstorff so you are thinking of setting utm_medium to social and leave campaign blank? or how would you think of setting medium? which tag would you use for whatsapp? utm_source?